# modifying a gerund with a counterfactual if-clause

Tags: conditional-constructions, gerunds, modifiers, conditionals

I'd like to know whether it is correct to modify a gerund with a counterfactual if-clause. Does the following sound okay?

> I like the idea of buying a castle if I were a billionaire.

Comment: I'd say it's OK. The _if_ clause, as you put it, is a modifier in the VP "buying a castle". Thus "buying a castle if I were a billionaire" is a constituent, a gerund-participial clause functioning as complement of the prep "of".

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The expression

`*I like the idea of buying a castle if I were a billionaire.`

is not correct. It has nothing to do with whether a gerund is involved, so let's leave it out.</strike>

`*I like the idea if I were a billionaire.`
is not correct.
This conditional sentence has to use "would". The following is correct:
`I would like the idea if I were a billionaire.`

Now that the structure is valid, the original expression is
`I would like the ides of buying a castle if I were a billionaire.`

**I think I misunderstood the OP.** Thanks to Gary and Apollyon for clarifying it for me. The question is, is the following expression, with a conditional modifying a gerund, valid:
`the idea of buying a castle if I were a billionaire`

I'm not at all sure. Is the following a valid sentence?

`The idea of buying a castle if I were a billionaire appeals to me.`

I think the original post's sentence sounds wrong, because the entire sentence sounds like a conditional, but put this way, I'm not sure.

Comment: What about "Buying a castle if I were a billionaire sounds like a good idea to me"?

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan That might be OK, since "buying a castle if I were a billionaire" amounts to a noun phrase in your sentence, and the entire sentence is not conditional. But who would say such a thing?

Comment: But "buying a caslte" is a gerund phrase, and it's modified by a counterfactual conditional there in  Gary Botnovcan's example. What exactly prevents the same from happening in the OP example?

Comment: A: What would you do if you were a billionaire? B: I would buy a caslte. Buying a medival building if I were megarich sounds like a good idea to me.

Comment: @Apollyon  Hmmm... In Gary's example, the verb "sounds" forces the interpretation" of what precedes it as a noun phrase. Can that interpretation be applied to the OP example? Maybe, but it seems a reach to me.

Comment: @Apollyon It seems I've misunderstood the thrust of your OP. I will edit my answer.

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan and Apollyon I've edited my post to retract my original opinion and repose the question with a less ambiguous example. Thanks to you both.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty In "The idea of buying a castle if I were a billionaire appeals to me," does the if-clause modify the gerund or the whole sentence?

Comment: @Apollyon I tried to put it so that it would modify the gerund, as an experiment, but I'm not sure that modifying a gerund with an if-clause is valid. It seems iffy.

Answer (score -1):

*If* is a conjunction like *and*, *or* or *but*.  It typically conjuncts two clauses.

That's what's happening here.

> [clause 1]:{ I like the idea of buying a castle } if [clause 2]:{ I were a billionaire }.

Clause 2 is not modifying clause 1 or anything in it.  The entirety of "I like the idea of buying a castle" is something that depends on condition "I were a billonaire."  Nothing in "I were a billonaire" connects back to anything more specific than that.

Now, written like this I think it's closer to what you are talking about

> I like the idea of buying, if I were a billionare, a castle.

but this only works with clear pauses/intonations in speech and commas in writing.  So I think this is something like a parenthetical structure, and again not a direct modifying relationship.

Comment: Even when regarded as a conjunction, it is *not* like "and" or "but".  The traditional label is "*subordinating* conjunction", and the resultant subordinate clause can act as a modifier or a supplement.  Also, "conjuncts" is a noun.  Did you mean "conjoins"?

Comment: A parenthetical structure and a modifying relationship are not mutually exclusive.